# How to Pass and read dynamic value in TOML

Tags: jvm-arguments, toml

in below code snipped I am trying to pass testPassword dynamically, inside my TOML file.
 for example I have this keystore password in some filePath (/etc/certs/keystore-pwd) of development environment.
 I am trying here to read this file password and set into value in below TOML property.

```
 [keystore.properties]
    security_keystore_password= "testPassword"
```

or we pass a variable as jvm argument and read in TOML - is it possible .
Is above ask is supported by TOML or it's a out of box ask?